# Div ID Same - Multiple Hide/Show - What Missing?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

PHP:

```
<input type='checkbox' onChange='DoTheSwitch(1);'><div id='Hide1'>Hide</div> 1
<input type='checkbox' onChange='DoTheSwitch(2);'><div id='Hide2'>Hide</div> 2
<input type='checkbox' onChange='DoTheSwitch(3);'><div id='Hide3'>Hide</div> 3
<input type='checkbox' onChange='DoTheSwitch(4);'><div id='Hide4'>Hide</div> 4
<input type='checkbox' onChange='DoTheSwitch(5);'><div id='Hide5'>Hide</div> 5
```

JavaScript:

```
function DoTheSwitch(a){
    var h = getEl("Hide"+a+"").innerHTML;
    switch(h){
        case "Hide":
            getEl("Hide"+a+"").innerHTML = "Show";
            $('input[id^="Hide"]').click(function(){
                $('#HideAB'+$(this).val()).hide();
            });
            break;
        case "Show":
            getEl("Hide"+a+"").innerHTML = "Hide";
            $('input[id^="Hide"]').click(function(){
                $('#HideAB'+$(this).val()).show();
            });
            break;
    }
}
```

Output (Many Small Dots on Map):

```
<div id='HideAB".$Stat."' style='display:block;'></div>
```

Those "HideAB" will have a value of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6 based on what I pulled from Database.

What I'm trying to do (sleepyhead at the moment) is whenever a user select a check box "1", I want to hide all the HideAB with a value of 1, and uncheck to show, so forth.  How do I fix that in Javascript/JQuery part?

Comment: Your code is a mess! Inline stuff, mixing jQuery with plain Javascript and plus the question is not clear.

Comment: Please don't edit your question according to the answer. The idea with Stack Overflow is that people having a problem should be able to get help from old questions. If you fix the code according to the answer, it will be very hard for others to understand the question. Please roll back the edit (you can do that by clicking the "x min ago" link next to "edited").

Comment: Thanks, done and I'll add the new revision on the bottom (somewhere) Lol (grr not letting me, just yet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Id` should be unique across the page, that could be what's causing troubles. Try using a class instead if you have to handle several elements together.

Comment: @gdoron: Yes, in his code snippet it is unique, but in the text he writes *hide all the HideAB with a value of 1* which I interpret as multiple use of the same id.

Comment: Ok, changing to Class would be ideal as you say (came across few similar "question".  Now how do I go about fixing the JQuery part to recognize the class based on checkbox?  Thanks

Comment: jQuery class selectors start with a dot: `$(".Hide" + id).hide()`

Comment: There, just revised the above code, now everything works like it's supposed to, thanks Anders for pointing to the right direction :)